# Best strategy for complex hard-surface sculpt retopology

Tags: modifiers, workflow, topology

I have been having a huge amount of trouble finding the best way to go around retopologizing a model I made.

It has many curves, as well as many flat surfaces. There are also "seams" that are supposed to indicated paneling.

I have tried my usual methods that I use during my character creations (mirror+sub-surf+shrink wrap (if needed)), and have been unsuccessful all 5 times I have done this.

The closest I have gotten was modeling the panels separately, and joining them together afterwards. The problem with this is that the spacing between the panels was not an equal amount- and equated to a uneven and stylized version of the paneling.

Any pointers anyone has for this issue/technique used for this situation? [image: The original sculpt]

[image: First Retopology]
[image]

Comment: You might be interested in [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124867/35559)

Comment: This looks perfect! I will give this a shot, thank you!

Comment: Okay so I tried that method- which is super handy for making plating and bulkheads on flat surfaces, but I think my mesh has way too many different angles or rotations associated for the modifiers to handle. I am going to try and make a base mesh underneath, and figure out eye-balling the paneling again. Thank you for this tip, it will come in handy for making scenes!

Comment: Hmm.. yeah.. it's tricky, the panel boundaries bear no relation to the underlying geometry.. do the panels need to be in the geometry? Would your case allow a shader-only solution?

Comment: @RobinBetts I was thinking about that. Making a good topology and then baking the normals onto the new mesh. I have been somewhat intimidated by that method- as the geometry has been so destroyed from dyna-topo that I worry about correctly calculating edges and direction of faces