# How to automatize a wall pattern?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edges, faces, bevel

Im modelling this house, and Im looking to automatize de separation from this brick pattern. I started modelling from a plane, subdivided it and bevel those edges to separate the faces I wanted, then deleted the face where its supposed to go the gap. The problem with that, its that once Ive done done the bevel, I cant find a way to change that separation again in a precise way, like being able to change it from 5cm to 10cm all at once. I try using an add on called Jarch vis, and thoug im able to tweak those things, Im not able to change the pattern as a want it to be.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbf0Y.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgLzF.jpg

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps the *Bevel Modifier* is what you need. Then you can edit the bricks, and the bevel is added automatically (and can be changed or disabled anytime)

Comment: But how can that work for creating two separate faces from one?

Comment: Oh it doesn't, it just adds bevel procedurally.

Comment: Maybe OTT here, but you could check out this [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124867/35559) for procedural panelling