# Is there a way to invert a wireframe?

Tags: modeling, mesh, wireframe

[image: reference picture from my viewport]
Im curious if there is anyway to invert a wireframe so that it makes cuts in the mesh rather than form a wire, if anyone has a solution that would help in the scenario without using the wireframe modifier that would be appreciated as well, thank you

Comment: Makes cuts in the mesh?

Comment: maybe overlay this cube over the solid one, apply modifier and use boolean difference to cut wires out of another cube

Comment: Duplicate object, have one with wireframe modifier, add boolean?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a hack?

First, give your object a vertex group, set to a very low weight for all vertices.. mine's called 'Shell_VG'

Give your object an *Edge Split* modifier, on all edges, followed by a *Solidify* Modifier, set to fill the rim, and weight the 'Shell_VG' group.

[image]

Then a *Displace* modifier along normals to shrink the faces, and a *Mask* modifier aimed at the shell vertex group, set to a higher threshold than the one you set originally.

[image]

For the pink result:

[image]

If you don't mind solid faces, you can cut out all the masking steps.

Comment: This could be done with shaders, too, if you don't need the geometry, or you could use a variation on [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124867/35559), which uses bevels, rather than displacement..