# Hard surface modeling - How to model engraved lines?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm trying to model a sci-fi helmet, in particular those hollow lines that I marked in red color:

[image]

[image]

So far I have tried:

1. Boolean difference using super thin cubes
2. Modeling each part separately

Both methods are time consuming and I imagine there are better options. What kind of tools or methods you would recommend to do this sort of modeling?

Comment: [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124867/35559) is a quite flexible option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Method 1 - Split Vertices

Such engraved lines can be created by splitting vertices and using the *Solidify* and *Bevel* modifier. The vertices of edges can be split manually in *Edit* mode (<kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>) or mark them as *Sharp* and use the *Split Edge* modifier.

[image: edit mode]

The vertices around the circle are split manually, the others are marked as sharp.

[image: render result]

Modifier stack is:

- Subdivision Surface: *level*: `2`
- EdgeSplit: `[_]` *Edge Angle* (unchecked), `[X]` *Sharp Edges*
- Solidify: default values
- Bevel: *Segments*: `2`, *Limited Method*: `Angle`, *Angle*: `30°` (default)

Video: [Modeling Techniques Hardsurface in Blender combined - Pedro Augusto](https://youtu.be/oJbxu_GLMz0) (The part about panels comes towards the end of the video.)

## Method 2 - Boolean Modifier

Alternatively, you can copy the model parts, use the *Boolean* modifier (operation: *Difference*) to cut it out, and another *Boolean* modifier (operation: *Intersection*) on the copy to get the cut-out part. This way you have a deep cut between the parts. Finally, add a *Bevel* modifier to each part. And tick the *Shading* → `[X]` *Harden Normals* option in the Bevel modifier to fix the shading. 
Note: This requires in the *Object Data Properties* the *Normals* → `[X]` *Auto Smooth* setting to be activated.

The Bool Cutter object on the screenshot is 2 cubes join together. One cuts the sphere at the top, the other one cuts it at the bottom. The sphere is actually 2 spheres (one is the middle part, the other one is the top and bottom parts).

[image: cutted shpere]

Video: [Blender Hard Surface Modeling | Slice Operation](https://youtu.be/IRJCChNu_pQ)

## Method 3 - Mask Modifier

A flexible method that uses the existing edge loops of the mesh and *Bevel* and *Mask* modifiers to create the support loops and the gap. It's described here by Robin Betts:
[What is the best way to model the intersection of multiple hard-surface pieces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124599/what-is-the-best-way-to-model-the-intersection-of-multiple-hard-surface-pieces/124867#124867)

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed answer!