# How to make small notches in the mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm modeling a microwave and I'm stuck with making this little notches, which I highlighted in the reference picture. I tried to perform a boolean operation, but it didn't work out and I don't know why. I'm not sure if this was a good approach though. Just deleting faces doesn't work too because of subdiv.

Any help is appreciated!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this help you? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/214144/107598

Comment: What do you mean by "Just deleting faces doesn't work too because of subdiv", if you extrude inwards then add a bit of topology to sharpen the edges it should work fine

Comment: @Blunder thanks, I think this will help!

Comment: @moonboots thank you, I'll try it!