# Making MotoBug fangs

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make the fangs of MotoBug here:
[image]

I've tried using a cone and a cube, but I have failed to get either in the right shape. I've tried using some online instructions but they were from outdated versions of Blender.

Can anyone here provide assistance?

Comment: Hello ! Unless you can narrow down your question to specific problems, I suggest you go to a more back-and-forth platform like https://blenderartists.org/ cheers

Comment: This a lot opinion based question but I would use low poly (8 faces) cylinder, scale one side with 0 and add edge loops to give it some shape

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Box modeling should work. Use a small plane, place it at the tip and then extrude it and follow the outline of the reference. Then extrude it to make it 3D and smooth is with the smooth brush (Sculpt mode). Add more edge loops to put it into shape. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n6jk.jpg

Answer (score 0):

One approach to start with a plane. Placed at the bottom, at the tip of the fang. Then you can extrude the plane upwards. Keep the vertices on the outline. Once you have covered the whole shape add three edge loops in the middle (top-down):

[image: plane]

Done this, extrude the plane along the Y-axis to make it 3D. Add an edge loop in the middle to have more geometry to deform. Now, you can use the *Smooth* brush in *Sculpt* mode to smooth the edges and corners. Use a low strength (0.15).

[image: extruded]

Don't forget to [check the face orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216140/107598) and recalculate outside if necessary.

With help of the *Loop Tools* you can smooth the edge loops, too.

This is how it looks like with a few [engraved lines](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214144/hard-surface-modeling-how-to-model-engraved-lines/214165#214165), a level 2 *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and metallic materials:

[image: result]