# Intersection of multiple hard surface pieces

Tags: modifiers

I tried to reproduce the amazing answer of Robin Betts here:

[What is the best way to model the intersection of multiple hard-surface pieces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124599/what-is-the-best-way-to-model-the-intersection-of-multiple-hard-surface-pieces/124867#124867)

Unfortunately i couldn't make it.

This is my frustrating result:

[image]

my settings:

[image]

[image]

what did i make wrong that i didn't look that amazing as Robin's answer? and why is my ring not closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you've created the oblique edges with some *Fill* (<kbd>F</kbd>) while you should have used *Join* (<kbd>J</kbd>). *Fill* will create an edge over the existing face while *Join* will cut the face in 2 halves, which is supposed to happen here for the topology you're looking for.

Here if you select the face you'll see you have a unique face, delete the oblique edge and join the 2 vertices and it should work:

[image]

Comment: it is a shame how little i know! :( THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: hey we are all improving every day with Blender  ;)

Comment: yes we DO!!! ;)