# How to model an android face (clearly divided parts)?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

What is the efficient way to create this model in Blender?

**How can I create such surfaces?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Question Updated: Added some pictures.

Comment: hello, your question is a bit too broad, what are you talking about, material, modeling?

Comment: Modeling, how can I model surfaces like the white surfaces seen on the cyborg?

Comment: first model the whole head, then cut the different parts

Comment: How can I model such clean surfaces?  Can you give me step by step instructions?

Comment: "clean" is a bit vague, you need to model a head, cut it in several distinct parts, to make it slick give it a Subdivision Surface modifier (or subdivide it enough)

Comment: please tell in what part you are struggling

Comment: I do not know where to start to get the same shape?

Comment: You need to be able to model a head, if you don't know how to do it you need to watch some tutorials. Once done, choose some of the edges, bevel, delete the bevel faces, and you'll get several pieces of head

Comment: By "clean surfaces" I mean the white area that is very flat and has no wrinkles.

Comment: Could you send me some good recommendations on how to model such surfaces?

Comment: The modelling technique you're looking for is called "Hard surface modelling" as opposed to organic modelling. typing these terms in your favorite search engine will yield you some good material I'm sure. cheers

Comment: it's easy to make this kind of surface, create some faces and give them a Subdivision Surface modifier and you'll get something slick, could you please show what you've done so far? it will help to guess where you're stuck

Comment: Thanks, I will show the results in an hour or more. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've just tried [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124867/35559), too, which works quite nicely here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You first need to model the head, let's say it's Suzanne's head, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier and right click > *Shade Smooth* in order to make the surface round and smooth:

[image]

To cut the head in several pieces, select an edge, bevel it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

Then <kbd>X</kbd> to delete the faces:

[image]

Then rearrange a bit the topology if you want sharp edges, i.e. extrude the border edges. To give thickness give your object a *Solidify* modifier that you put above the *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

For the plastic material, you need a low *Roughness* value:

[image]

Comment: Hello, I have now recreated almost the same model, but how can I achieve the perfect surface color that has the android face? Here are my results so far: https://imgur.com/a/IaI44P0

Comment: you should try the settings of the Principled BSDF I show in my pictures, but I'll also try something else

Comment: I would like to thank you for your efforts. 

Comment: @oapve, I'm not sure you can do it with Metallic at 1, like a kind of white metal, but just playing with Roughness seems to work, like in the settings I show in my screenshot, have you tried? It looks like you're using the Metallic value...

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to create that is to first sculpt the head in Blender's sculpt mode. After you sculpt a detailed head model, I would box model the shape of the the part that is cut out in the front of the face. Then I would overlap the cutout shape over the sculpt, and then use the boolean modifier, to cut the shape out of the head sculpt. Then, I would retopologize the head sculpt, so that the model is smooth and less dense. Also, you will need to duplicate the head sculpt, and boolean away the other parts, to make a separate mesh for the glass visor on the front. And I would retopologize the glass part as well. It also looks like the white piece is actually pretty thin, so  After retopoligy, I would give it the solidify modifier, and also possibly the sub-surf modifier, to give it some thickness and smooth out the object. Hope this helps!