# Realistic sewing patterns - sewing cloth around an object

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, topology

I'm trying to simulate realistic sewing patterns, and so I can not always lay my mesh around my character.

Here I am trying to make a sleeve by connecting two edges of a plane, as a tailor would do. If I directly sew them together, the strings would be in the way when the simulation starts, and the arm would not be inside the sleeve.
My solution for now is making an extra edge, so that the strings go around the arm. However, this creates an additional pulling force on the x axis, that "rolls up" the sleeve. So while maybe a workaround, but not an ideal solution.

Is there a better way to do this?

[image: mesh before simulation]

<sup>Mesh before simulation</sup>

[image: result with described method]

<sup>Result with described method</sup>

Comment: obvious solution: deleting the edge along the x axis underneath the arm.

Answer (score 0):

Bend the mesh of the sleeves a little to create the desired shape. Select the faces at one side and use the 3D Cursor as pivot point (<kbd>.</kbd>) to rotate them. Then do the same for the other side of the sleeve.

In my experience, it doesn't matter if the threads (wires) penetrate the model's body. However, the fabric mesh should not penetrate the body of the model because of the collision detection.

[image: sewing pattern]

Note that Blender only shortens the threads but doesn't merge the mesh. So usually, there still will be visible gaps and you have to remove them manually.

[image: sewing result]

Before sewing, mark the seams as (UV) seams. Then run the simulation, apply the *Cloth* modifier. Now in *Edit* mode, select a thread (wire) with *Edge Selection* mode (<kbd>2</kbd>) and choose *Select Similar > Amount of Faces Around an Edge* from the menu to select them all. Now, you can merge them all with <kbd>M</kbd>, *Merge > Collapse*.

Since you have marked the seams you can easily UV unwrap the mesh and you can [use modifiers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124867/107598), a shader, or *Geometry Nodes* to add visible seams to the clothes.