# Cloth Sewing Issues

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, sewing

I'm working on making some clothes, specifically this shirt design:

[image]

However, I'm running into some issues with the cloth simulation

The first, is that the top side of the sleeve ends up pinched into a sharp edge and isn't "falling" onto the top of the arm:

[image]

The second is here at the collar. As you can see it's not going forward enough on the neckline, and it's bunching up in the rear:

[image]

Third, the back of the shirt is bunching up here in back, rather than hanging down naturally.

Here's the mesh, which is modeled on the actual pattern:

[image]

[image]

I've tried subdividing the mesh further, adding a Solidify modifier, I've tweaked the cloth physics, made several adjustments to the height and width of the front and back pieces, added additional loops to make the collar bigger, but am not having any luck getting things to lay right.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: On real garments, the sleeves are sewn together at the bottom. The collar and the cuffs of the sleeves can be created separately and then added to the pin group. Here is a related question with an example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/306797/107598. and here is [A Tailor's Approach to Cloth Sewing in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-KPPKZecs8&list=PLeo08VYpYn82JZGSjcWMS8WHOW_wsPP2w) on YT. It's a very detailed and very accurate "tutorial" that might be helpful. (It's more like a course/live stream (8 hours) but you can watch it at 2x speed.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. I made the collar one piece and used a Bend modifier through the Simply Cloth plugin to curve to the shape I wanted before sewing it.